# How can I set the default setting for dual monitors (using Win+P)?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have two displays (one monitor and one TV) connected to my card via DVI. I switch between them with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (when I'm using XBMC I set "only projector"). Most of the time, I use it during late hours, so I just turn off the PC (with XBMC's option "shutdown") and go to sleep. All fine, but on the next day my display is changed (to "only projector").

Bottom line is - how can I set my Windows 7 to have "only monitor" each time system boots?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you wouldn't just leave both active?  It would prevent the switching.  Just turn off the device you're not using at the time.

Comment: Yes, my monitor has broken switch. Turning it off means 30 minutes or so of struggling to switch it back on.

Comment: I figured it out. All you need to do is create a shortcut for `DisplaySwitch.exe` (`indows\system32\DisplaySwitch.exe`) with parameter "internal". Then place it in Autostart. And voila ;)

Comment: @TomekBuszewski Put it in as a (descriptive) answer. You're allowed to do that.  You may have to wait a few hours first though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Create a shortcut for `Windows\system32\DisplaySwitch.exe /internal`and place it in StartUp. If this doesn't work, make a registry edit to place it in Autorun:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
>   Name = Name of the application
>   Type = REG_SZ (String)
>   Data ="C:\Windows\system32\DisplaySwitch.exe" /internal